# BETWEEN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I get the numbers between 4 and 8. The answer I want is 5,6,7 but the script returns 4,5,6,7,8 when used in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE numbers BETWEEN '4' AND '8'
```

Comment: If those are numbers (a numeric datatype), you should *not* put them in quotes! Otherwise you'll incur implicit conversion - use `WHERE numbers BETWEEN 4 AND 8` instead - no need for any quotes at all

Comment: `'41'` *is* between `'4'` and `'8'`, but `41` is not between `4` and `8`. Don't threat numbers as strings, they are not!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive. From MSDN:

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than
>   or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to
>   the value of end_expression.

Since it is inclusive you will want to use greater than and less than:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE numbers > 4
   AND numbers < 8
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bf87/2)

If you want to use the `BETWEEN` operator then you would need to shorten the range:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE numbers between 5 AND 7
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bf87/5)